# When Excel opens it links to a file which I cannot find, it's not present in the formula, how can I find and delete it?

Tags: excel, linker

When I open Excel and it loads in the right left corner I see Linking:testfile.xlsm however I would like to remove this. How can I find this file and remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Check in Name Manager. You might find it there.